# How can I display a ASP.NET server control that is declared on a base master page?

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, master-pages

My solution, for several different reasons which I won't get into now, has several different ASP.NET Web Application projects, all of which will share several features of the master page. To achieve that I have a separate Class Library project which all the Web App projects reference, that among other things includes a BaseMasterPage class which inherits from System.Web.UI.MasterPage.

My intention is to have all master pages of all the Web Apps inherit from BaseMasterPage, which works fine for regular properties and methods, but I am now trying to add a server control I created to the BaseMasterPage and have this displayed in the actual master pages but I don't know how to make the property from BaseMasterPage that has the control visible on the actual master page without a lot of ugly code.

Anybody has any ideas on how to do this?

If it helps, this is a snippet of my BaseMasterPage (and HierarchicalMenu is my custom server control):

```
public class BaseMasterPage : MasterPage
{
    private HierarchicalMenu _leftMenu;

    public HierarchicalMenu LeftMenu
    {
        get
        {
            return _leftMenu;
        }
        set
        {
            _leftMenu = value;
        }
    }
}
```

If I add the following to my Site.master page, a HierarchicalMenu gets displayed but it is not the one declared by the property in the BaseMasterPage:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="BaseMasterPage" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <cc1:HierarchicalMenu ID="LeftMenu" runat="server" MenuName="Left Menu" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

What I would really like it not to have to add a HierarchicalMenu straight on my Site.master like I did up there, and have it be the one from the BaseMasterPage.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually I have just found out that when I manipulate the _LeftMenu_ on the code of the _BaseMasterPage_ the _LeftMenu_ of my _Site.master_ is updated, so somehow the HierarchicalMenu added to the Site.master is linked to the property of the same name in BaseMasterPage.

Answer (score 0):

I can see three ways of solving this both has its own merits & demertis.

1. Expose a new virtual folder from your app's Virtual directory in IIS and map it to a common location, where you can find your BaseMasterPage.master. Then instruct the Master page in your application to be nested master page of BaseMasterPage.master (the virtual path to be specified will be the virtual folder we created). Similarly all your web apps would have a virtual directory within itself pointing to this common location. This is a good way to achieve nested Visual inheritance
2. In your BaseMasterPage you can dynamically create the controls (not just exposing them as properties) and add it to the Form tag in the constructor of the BaseMasterPage.
3. You may have to hack an approach where the .master file would get compiled to an assembly. Some pointers are

   - http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/creating-asp-net-user-control-libraries-in-visual-studio-2010/
   - http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/UserControls/UserControls.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Ramesh. This is good stuff. For the moment I have sorted it out with my Site.master having its code file partial class inherit my BaseMasterPage. I then add the same controls my BaseMasterPage has to my Site.master, with the same names, and on the Page_Load of my Site.master I do this for all my controls: base.MyControl = this.MyControl. The problem with this approach is that I will always get a warning saying SiteMaster.MyControl hides inherited member BaseMasterPage.MyControl, but things are working just fine.